# How do I make sure a URL is an image using JavaScript + jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my web application, users can post text to a feed, and the text may include URL's. My code scans for URL's and replaces them which anchor tags pointed at the URL's. I want to change this so that my code can detect whether or not the URL points to an image, and if it does, render an image tag inside the anchor tag, instead of just the URL text.

I can do this on server side code by sending a quick 'HEAD' request to the URL to see what the Content-Type is on the response, and this works reliably. However, it doesn't scale well for obvious reasons.

What would be better is if I could push this logic onto the client's browser. I'd like to use JavaScript + jQuery to send the 'HEAD' request to the specified URL, and read the Content-Type header from the response.

I know that cross-domain requests are an issue. Could I somehow use JSONP? What options do I have?

## EDIT - SECURITY RISK

I got some good answers to my question, but I wanted to point out something in big bold letters. As Adam pointed out in the comments, this is a security risk. If you can guarantee the URL's of the images are all coming from trusted domains, you're good to go with this solution. However, in my scenario, users can enter whatever URL they want. This means they could create their own site which requires basic authentication, and then when the jQuery runs to set the src attribute on the created image, the user is presented with a username/password dialog, and that's obviously a **huge** risk.

Comment: Can you check the file extension in the URL is an image extension?

Comment: I'd say SECURITY is an issue.  Accepting strings and writing them out to the page like this for links is a scary prospect.  Even if you're sanitizing your inputs, a rogue URL like www.viruses.com/getone.jpg could still be perfectly "legitimate" and harmful.  I hope you've considered these (and many other) attack vectors.  Client-side options are not good for validation of an appropriate link beyond simple string parsing (looking for ".jpg" or something, for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to load it in a hidden img element:

```
$('<img />').attr('src', url).load(function () { 
    alert('url contains an image'); 
}).error(function () {
    alert('url is no image');
});
```

Comment: I think this is a really beautiful solution since it doesn't force us to provide a list of image extensions.

Comment: jea, and it can still work for say a ".php" file which acts as image which would be blocked if you just look at the file-extension

Comment: The only problem with this is that if the image is on a domain that requires basic auth to access the image, or any other kind of auth, the browser will pop up a username/password dialog. So this opens your users up to phishing-style attacks. :/

Answer (score 2):

you can create a javascript `Image` object you will try loading all the links like this:

```
myImageObject = new Image();

// handle an URL
myImageObject.onload = function(e) {
    alert('it is an image');
}

myImageObject.src = 'http://www.google.bg/images/srpr/logo3w.png';
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VQP3g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

just check if the string they gave you ends with .jpg, .png, .gif etc.
if it ends with any extension like that its an image.
if not its, its a normal URL.

Comment: This doesn't always work: [text in .gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HTML-old.gif), [image without extension](http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRX4vJV0QlvkzYIR1PPvTxD3Wncm1K66u91agm0PFotr6DYNYh_Oap9xJazPQ).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use AJAX to load the URL then call getResponseHeader() to get the content type.

In jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "www.example.com/SomeImage.jpg",
  success: function(output, status, xhr) {
    if(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")== "image/jpeg") {
      // insert image into page
    }
    else {
      // render url text
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the header info using ajax calls using `XMLHttpRequestObject.open("HEAD", url);` and `XMLHttpRequestObject.getAllResponseHeaders();` but this works only with your own domain or the the with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` header set.

JSONP uses `script` tag and am pretty sure it can't get any header info.